# Get value from a Rails nested hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails nested hash as follow:

```
class = [{"tutor" => {"id" => "Me"}}, {"tutor" => {}}]
```

I would like to extract id list, but the nested hash can be nil:

```
tutor_ids = class.map {|c| c['tutor']['id'].to_i }
```

In case the nested hash is nil, I'll get error.

How do I go about this?

Comment: Multiple keys with the same name? Here `class` is essentially is `{"tutor" => {}}`. Is there a more elaborate example?

Comment: class is a reserved word BTW. Standard practice is to write it with a K, as in *klass*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I think you were probably thinking of an array of hashes like so (given the same key was used multiple times:

`klass = [{"tutor" => {"id" => "Me"}},{"tutor" => {}}]`

Then you could map the tutor IDs with:

`tutor_ids = klass.map {|k| k['tutor'] && k['tutor']['id'] }.compact`

which would result in

`=> ["Me"]`

Compact will throw out all the nil values encountered afterwards.

Comment: I was curious if there was a 'cleaner' way of calling `try` for nested hashes, but that only works on object methods.

Comment: BTW in Ruby 2.3.x we gained the `dig` operator making this a bit easier on the eyes now.
`tutor_ids = klass.map {|k| k.dig(:tutor, :id) }.compact`

Answer (score 0):

```
id = class['tutor'] ? class['tutor']['id'] : nil
```

Comment: Is there a way I can use it in a `map`?